# Why is this SQL CAST performatic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I was refactoring a heavy and very badly written stored procedure in SQL Server when I saw this code in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SET @SELECT = @SELECT + '
          CAST(LOG_MODULO.DataHora AS DATE) >= '''+ @DATAINI + ''' AND
          LOG_MODULO.DataHora  <= '''+ @DATAFIM +' 23:59:00'' ' ;
```

`LOG_MODULO.DataHora` is a `DATETIME` column, `@DATAINI` and `@DATAFIM` are `VARCHAR(15)` variables, and yes, this query is constructed via string concatenation.

I refactored this to:

```
AND LOG_MODULO.DataHora BETWEEN @DATAINI AND @DATAFIM + ' 23:59:59'
```

But my version takes 5x the time to run than its predecessor.

Why is this? What should be a good way to code this without changing the input?

Comment: You kept your refactored code in dynamic sql right?  Or did you take it out and use regular t-sql?

Comment: I used regular t-sql.

Comment: I would make your variables datetime. And then change the second one to be < DATEADD(day, 1, @DATAINI). Between can be quite confusing and in your case you have the possibility of missing data that is in the last second of the day. Might not be a big deal but...

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the input. Thanks for the tips, nevertheless.

Comment: Then create a new variable that is datetime.

Comment: Here is an excellent article on the pitfalls of between. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: Sqlserver sometimes seems to choose the better execution plan when using hardcoded values in the where clause, compared to using variables. And the dynamic sql makes them kinda hardcoded to the optimizer.

Comment: @LukStorms I thought this could be the case.

Comment: Well, it's possible to give a [hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql) to the query optimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you converted it out of dynamic sql, with regular SQL, I would declare @datafim2 as datetime and set to dateadd(day,1,@datafim) ... then do dataHora >= @DataIni and datahora < @datafim2.  Point being make the data types of your column the same as your variables.

Comment: Solved it, thank you =).  I'm still curious about what is happening behind the curtains, though.

Comment: It is doing an implicit data type conversion on the column in the table, which removes the use of indexes and makes queries take a lot longer.